# Tag and link syntax doesn't seem to like each other, they want to be more separated!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown-rendering

This produce a tag, some text and a link:

[sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag) [some link][1](https://example.com)

```
[tag:sometag] [some link][1]
```

Adding an space produce a tag and a link

[sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag)  [some link](https://example.com)

```
[tag:sometag]  [some link][1]
```

There's one space difference between both. Adding any other character produce the same effect, independently where it's added.